# Invalid Syntax error on print statement in python 3.2.2

Tags: syntax, python-3.x

I'm getting a syntax error when I attempt to run my program and the print in the last line is highlighted in red. I don't understand why there is a syntax error.

```
# 6. Calculate the radius of the circle using the
#      distance formula on a given point and the center
r = math.sqrt((a-x)** + (b-y)**

# 7. Output to the shell the location of the center
#    of the circle
print("The center of the circle is at (",x,",", y,")",sep="")

# 8. Output to the shell the radius of the circle              
print("The radius of the circle is " , r)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r = math.sqrt((a-x)** + (b-y)**
```

should probably be

```
r = math.sqrt((a-x)**2 + (b-y)**2)
```

The missing closing paren makes the expression spread out to the following lines.  Up to the `print()` call in the last line, the expression conforms to Python's grammar (even if this appears surprising at first).

Comment: i tried as you suggested but now i get an invalid syntax error on that closing parentheses.